# How to list folders in raw resources

Tags: android

I have a huge directory of infrared remote control codes, and I'd like to parse through each of them when needed. However, I am having issues trying to access the folders I have in my application's res/raw/ folder. I'd like to be able to get the folder names, because that would essentially sort for me and list out all the brands that I'd like to list in a Spinner, and then pull files from inside that folder later.

What's wrong with me doing something like this?

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/res/raw/";
File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for(File inFile : files){
    if(inFile.isDirectory()){
        Log.d(TAG, inFile.getName());
    }
}
```

Just found out that I can't create subdirectories in my res/raw folder, and I'd have to go about this through the assets folder. Would this be as simple as this structure?

```
assets
    - remotes
        - Samsung
            - remote1.txt
            - remote2.txt
        - Sony
            - remote1.txt
        - etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am having issues trying to access the folders I have in my application's res/raw/ folder.

You cannot have folders inside of `res/raw/`. A resource directory can contain files, not subdirectories.

If you want to package a directory tree with your app, use `assets/` and `AssetManager`, not raw resources.

Comment: I edited my original post. So, would that structure for subdirectories work?

Comment: @ThomasSmythe: That directory structure is certainly possible. Whether it fits your business needs, I can't say.

Comment: this is not an answer but suggestion.Use Firebase for storing the data of each file and retrieve when ever necessary. This decreases the no. of files you are stored in the build and also provide dynamic approach if any content of file needs to be changed.